# "giving up after" command not fully working in Mavericks

Tags: applescript, osx-mavericks

I encountered a mysterious bug with AppleScript and OSX 10.9.1.

This code works inside AppleScript Editor, but when I save it as an application, "giving up after" doesn't work. It works in my other computer with 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) though. Does anyone know what's the issue? Thanks!

```
global fullTime
global chosenTime
set pickFromList to {1, 2}
choose from list the pickFromList with prompt "Next message will dissapear after 1 + x seconds. Choose x!"
set chosenTime to result as text
add1sec()
display dialog "Click OK and the next dialog box will appear in " & fullTime & " seconds"
delay fullTime
display dialog "Works! But now this should dissapear after " & fullTime & " seconds" giving up after fullTime
on add1sec()
    set fullTime to chosenTime + 1
end add1sec
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to OSX 10.9.2 fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this:

```
set pickFromList to {1, 2}
set chosenTime to (choose from list the pickFromList with prompt "Next message will dissapear after 1 + x seconds. Choose x!") as number

set fullTime to add1sec(chosenTime)

display dialog "Click OK and the next dialog box will appear in " & fullTime & " seconds"
delay fullTime
tell application "SystemUIServer" to display dialog "Works! But now this should dissapear after " & fullTime & " seconds" giving up after fullTime


on add1sec(startTime)
    return startTime + 1
end add1sec
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually made me understand the proper use of handlers, but unfortunately it doesn't change the behaviour. Last dialog box won't disappear when I run this as an application.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this actually did solve the "giving up after" -problem, but it also created another one. Now that this is used:

```
tell application "SystemUIServer" to display dialog "Works! But now this should disappear after " & fullTime & " seconds" giving up after fullTime
```

First of all, the dialog box is not "connected" to the running application anymore, so that I can't make it active by clicking the application icon in dock. Second, if "giving up after" is longer than 2 minutes the default timeout occurs.